# Why does an explicit static call on a concrete class that returns 'Self?' fail casting, but an implicit static call to that same method works fine?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

Given the following class...

```
final class MyClass : Codable {
    var someDate:Date
}
```

And this extension on it...

```
extension Decodable{

    static func decodeFromJson(_ json:Data?) -> Self?{
        return nil // Implementation not needed for example
    }

    static func decodeFromJson(_ json:Data?, withDateFormat dateFormat:String) -> Self?{
        return nil // Implementation not needed for example
    }
}
```

When writing an extension directly against `MyClass`...

```
extension MyClass{

    static func decodeFromJson(_ json:Data?) -> Self?{

        let dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        // This line won't compile
        // return MyClass.decodeFromJson(json, withDateFormat:dateFormat) 

        // This line compiles just fine
        return decodeFromJson(json, withDateFormat:dateFormat)
    }
}
```

The line above that won't compile gives you this error

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'MyClass?' to return type 'Self?'
```

It was an accident that I found the latter works. I thought I was DOA.

So why does the latter work whereas the former doesn't?

Comment: Why are you using two separate methods? Use **one** with a default value for `dateFormat`:  `static func decodeFromJson(_ json:Data?, withDateFormat dateFormat:String = "")...` Then you can omit the second parameter. The date format is valid if it's not empty.

Comment: This is simplifed code and that particular part I don't believe is related to my question, which is why does calling the static from within the class vs calling it via the class type yield different results when they're the same exact method?

Comment: Just adding more, there are actual several overloads.  Also, setting it to "" is not correct as an empty string is not acceptable.  We can't use optionals here either as another overload already uses an optional which would make a call without a 2nd argument ambiguous.  Again though, that's separate from the question about the compiler.